# Can't crop specific part of image for profile picture

Tags: html, css, image, size, crop

I'm wanting to essentially take an image and crop a section of it with CSS.

Here's the picture I'd like to use.

[image]

Here's how I'd like to crop it

[image]

So, here's the code that I'm using right now.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.staffboxes {
  background: white;
  width: 15%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: #dedede solid 1px;
}

.staffpfp {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="staffdesign.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Staff Page</h3>

  <div class="staffboxes">
    <p>
      <div class="staffpfp"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/f505l.png" alt="Kouhai's DP" /></div>
      <h3>Kouhai</h3>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here's what comes out

[image]

If you could please help me, I'd appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is set your image to `width: 100%` and height to `auto` to prevent distortion.

This way, if you change the overall size of `.staffpfp` class in the future, the `img` inside will adapt accordingly.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

.staffboxes {
  background: white;
  width: 15%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: #dedede solid 1px;
}

.staffpfp {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.staffpfp img{width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="staffdesign.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

  <h3>Staff Page</h3>

  <div class="staffboxes">
    <p>
      <div class="staffpfp"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/f505l.png" alt="Kouhai's DP" /></div>
      <h3>Kouhai</h3>
    </p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are AWESOME!

Comment: I won't, it just won't let me for another 30 seconds, LOL!